# Find $5x^3+11y^3+13z^3=0$ integer solutions

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, invariance

Problem statement:
Find all integer solutions of equation $5x^3+11y^3+13z^3=0$.

My attempt:
I tried to reason that if there's a solution, then, since we have odd powers of variables we have 4 different scenarios to explore:

1) $5x^3 = 11y^3 + 13z^3$

2) $11y^3 = 5x^3 + 13z^3$

3) $13z^3 = 5x^3 + 11y^3$

4) $13z^3 = 5x^3 = 11y^3$. Since there are constant numbers $13$, $5$, and $11$ before variables, the only integer that would make all three equal would be $\boxed{0}$

While my road of thought is leading me to something, I think that I am doing something in a little bit too complicated way.

A few hints:

1. This question is from a chapter about invariance.
2. The problem is asked just after $x^3 - 3y^3 - 9z^3 = 0$, which is solved when you show that, if $(x, y, z)$ is a solution, then $(\frac{x}{3^n}, \frac{y}{3^n}, \frac{z}{3^n})$, where $n$ is any natural number, is also a solution. So, it seems that this equation should be solved in a similar manner.
3. It should not be very complicated - it is just beginning of a high school level book.

Comment: See here: http://sci4um.com/about18431.html

Comment: @Rohan already looked there, but it seems that they had not solved the problem there.

Comment: Ok, then no problem.

Comment: Your first step looks wrong. The sum $S=11y^3+13z^3$ needs to be divisible by 5, but that doesn't mean $y$ and $z$ need to. In fact you can take cube roots mod 5, so for any $z$ mod 5, there's a corresponding $y$ so that 5 divides $S$.

Comment: @Tad, you are right! Thank you for spotting my mistake!

Comment: It's also a hint - look at the equation mod 13, since there are fewer cubes mod 13.

Comment: $11(2)^3+13(7)^3\equiv 0\pmod5$ but neither $2^3$ nor $7^3$ are multiples of $5$. They are just congruent modulo $5$. You have to edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at cubes modulo $13$ and show that $x$ or $y$ is divisible by $13$, then follow the proof for the equation $x^3 - 3y^3 - 9z^3 = 0$.