# Solve $5x^3 + 11y^3 + 13z^3 = 0$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have been trying to solve $5x^3 + 11y^3 + 13z^3 = 0$ over the integers, but I did not know how to do it. Just by looking at this equation, I guessed there aren't any integer solutions, but I do not know how to prove it. Is there a simple way of solving this equation? I would be grateful for all help.

Comment: I think it's already answered here long ago https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2078486/find-5x311y313z3-0-integer-solutions